# Cannot find table 1 .IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

This for inserting student in the database, 
a dataset is returned after the insertion is completed.
Same stored procedure is used for inserting and modifying the student details based on student ID.
Insert returns two tables where as modify returns a single table .During modify, the exception is raised at the inside if statement

```
if (dsFeeTransaction != null && dsFeeTransaction.Tables.Count > 0 && dsFeeTransaction.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0 ||dsFeeTransaction != null && dsFeeTransaction.Tables.Count > 0 && dsFeeTransaction.Tables[1].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    if(dsFeeTransaction != null && dsFeeTransaction.Tables.Count > 0 && dsFeeTransaction.Tables[1].Rows.Count > 0)
                     lblID.Text = dsFeeTransaction.Tables[1].Rows[0][0].ToString();
                    MessageBox.Show(dsFeeTransaction.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString());
                    btnAssign.Enabled = true;
                }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've solved this by making the following change to the inside if statement.

```
if(dsFeeTransaction != null && dsFeeTransaction.Tables.Count > 1 && dsFeeTransaction.Tables[1].Rows.Count > 0)
```

Comment: So what you are saying is that you used my answer?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to require there to be 2 tables or more not one or more so change this

```
dsFeeTransaction.Tables.Count > 0
```

to this

```
dsFeeTransaction.Tables.Count > 1
```

Comment: It doesn't make any difference does it?

Comment: @saurabh64 it does, because then the index will never be out of range and you will not get the exception